# nested queries in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to query something from my MySql db via sequelize ORM in nodejs.

My associations looks something like this:

```
ResourceModel.belongsTo(models.ModuleM, {
    foreignKey: 'moduleId',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});

ResourceModel.hasMany(models.ResourceItemM, {
    foreignKey: 'resourceId',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});

ResourceModel.hasMany(models.ResourceComponentM, {
    foreignKey: 'resourceId',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});
```

I am trying to get the item type and module name for my resources using this:

```
ResourceModel.findAll({


limit: 5,
  attributes: [
    ['resource_name', 'RESOURCE NAME'],
    ['res_code', 'RESOURCE CODE']
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.ModuleM,
      attributes: [
        ['module_name', 'MODULE']
      ]
    },
    {
      model: models.ResourceItemM,
      attributes: [
        ['item_type', 'ITEM TYPE']
      ]
    }
  ]
}).then((data)=> {
  console.log('data: ', data);
})
.catch((err)=> {
  console.log('Something went wrong: ', err);
})
```

Now when I am doing this I get a error saying: `Unknown column \'ResourceModel.moduleId\' in \'on clause\'',`

When I do this without the second include object, it works fine but this fails. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you check you database, that there is `moduleId` column in `ResourceModel` table?

Comment: Yeah I did that. I guess that's pretty obvious. My model file indeed has a field named moduleId. I did solve the problem. Will be posting the answer as soon as I get some time.